# Get IIS console error using in console application C#

Tags: c#, iis, iis-express

I need to get IIS console error for web application through C# console application. how to take this console error report in c# console application. is it possible?
[image]

Comment: That looks like a client side error thrown from a javascript file. Unless the javascript is calling code from your C# app which is throwing the error, you cannot see the error from your app. Just click on the error and see where it takes you.

Comment: If this is a pure client side error, then you can't log it in c# console application. However, if the error is caused by server side, then you should focus on logging exception from your IIS application instead of collecting javascript error.